# How can I obtain a list of all existing databases in DB2 using the JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

Through the DB2 command line I can obtain a [list of all existing database](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001961.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-4-64) through this command:

```
LIST DATABASE DIRECTORY
```

Is there away to do something similar from a JDBC app?

My goal is to delete a bunch of databases that start with a specific name.
Example:

```
XYZ01
XYZ02
XYZ07
FOO01
```

I want to delete every database starts with XYZ.

Is there some kind of metadata database that contain such information?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not using JDBC. Check this thread: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1667811-get-a-list-of-all-databases-on-a-DB2-instance

Comment: Besides, you wouldn't be able to drop a database via JDBC anyway.